# how to add the e.getmessage() in return for a java method

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to add the exception in the return result incase of any issues in the below method?

I tried the below way but receiving validation error message

```
 Multiple markers at this line
- e cannot be resolved to a variable
- e cannot be resolved 


@RestController
public class RunnerController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/run", method=RequestMethod.POST)    
    public String runScript(@RequestParam Integer order) {      
        try{
            //some code here//
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            log.error("An unexpected error occurred when attempting to run script. The error was: " + e.getMessage() + ".", e);
        }
        return ("An unexpected error occurred running script. The error was: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: what validation error?

Comment: `e` is not visible outside the `catch` block, you may want to `return` directly inside the `catch` block .

Comment: The best thing you can do is to remove the try/catch entirely.  If your code throws checked exceptions, add them to the `throws` clause of your method.  Your client code should be checking for a failure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chagne code as below

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/run", method=RequestMethod.POST)    
    public String runScript(@RequestParam Integer order) {     
    String message = null;
        try{
            //some code here//
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      message = e.getMessage();
        log.error("An unexpected error occurred when attempting to run script. The error was: " + e.getMessage() + ".", e);
    }
        return message != null ? message : "something that you want to return";

    }
```

or you can return error message directly from catch.

Answer (score 2):

What if you return it in the catch block, like

```
public class RunnerController { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/run", method=RequestMethod.POST)    
    public String runScript(@RequestParam Integer order) {      
        try{
            //some code here//
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            log.error("An unexpected error occurred when attempting to run script. The error was: " + e.getMessage() + ".", e);
            return ("An unexpected error occurred running script. The error was: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return ("No unexpected error occurred running script");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return your exception `e` in the `catch` because it's not visible outside